# How to allow child widgets to render correctly

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a custom frame in WxWidgets, and a custom button (for a game interface).
The button should highlight in another colour (grey) when the mouse hovers over it.
When the button is in a WxFrame it works correctly.
When the button is in the custom frame it doesn't, although it is receiving the required events.

I'd be grateful for some pointer as to why this happens and what to do about it.
I am new to WxWidgets and to C++.

EDIT: I've just discovered that if i change the colour of the brush on the button to a 'proper' colour ie. dc.SetBrush( *wxRED_BRUSH); then it works. As to why? I am none the wiser. Can anyone help?

Thanks

The custom frame:

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <format>
#include "aeFrame.h"


BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(aeFrame, wxPanel)

    EVT_ENTER_WINDOW(aeFrame::mouseEnteredWindow)
    EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW(aeFrame::mouseLeftWindow)
    EVT_PAINT(aeFrame::paintEvent)

END_EVENT_TABLE()

aeFrame::aeFrame(wxWindow* parent, int frameWidth, int frameHeight) :
 wxWindow(parent, wxID_ANY)
{
    SetMinSize( wxSize(frameWidth, frameHeight) );
    this->frameWidth = frameWidth;
    this->frameHeight = frameHeight;
}

void aeFrame::paintEvent(wxPaintEvent & evt)
{

    wxPaintDC dc(this);
    render(dc);
}

void aeFrame::paintNow()
{

    wxClientDC dc(this);
    render(dc);
}

void aeFrame::render(wxDC&  dc)
{
    dc.SetBrush( *wxBLACK_BRUSH);
    dc.SetPen( *wxWHITE_PEN );
    
    dc.DrawRectangle( 0, 0, this->frameWidth, this->frameHeight );
}

void aeFrame::mouseEnteredWindow(wxMouseEvent& event)
{ 
    paintNow();
}
void aeFrame::mouseLeftWindow(wxMouseEvent& event)
{
    paintNow();
}
```

the custom button:

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <format>
#include "aeButton.h"


BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(aeButton, wxPanel)

    EVT_LEFT_DOWN(aeButton::mouseDown)
    EVT_LEFT_UP(aeButton::mouseReleased)
    EVT_ENTER_WINDOW(aeButton::mouseEnteredWindow)
    EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW(aeButton::mouseLeftWindow)
    EVT_PAINT(aeButton::paintEvent)

END_EVENT_TABLE()

aeButton::aeButton(wxWindow* parent, int buttonWidth, int buttonHeight, wxString text) :
 wxWindow(parent, wxID_ANY)
{
    SetMinSize( wxSize(buttonWidth, buttonHeight) );
    this->text = text;
    this->buttonWidth = buttonWidth;
    this->buttonHeight = buttonHeight;
    pressedDown = false;
}

void aeButton::paintEvent(wxPaintEvent & evt)
{

    wxPaintDC dc(this);
    render(dc);
}

void aeButton::paintNow()
{

    wxClientDC dc(this);
    render(dc);
}

void aeButton::render(wxDC&  dc)
{
    if (mouseOver) 
        dc.SetBrush( wxColor(10,10,10, 5));
    else
        dc.SetBrush( *wxBLACK_BRUSH);

    if (pressedDown)
        dc.SetPen( *wxWHITE_PEN );
    else
        dc.SetPen( *wxLIGHT_GREY_PEN );
    
    dc.DrawRectangle( 0, 0, this->buttonWidth, this->buttonHeight );

    wxCoord textWidth, textHeight;
    dc.GetTextExtent(this->text, &textWidth, &textHeight);

    int xpos = (this->buttonWidth - textWidth) /2;
    int ypos = (this->buttonHeight- textHeight) /2;

    dc.DrawText( this->text, xpos, ypos );
}

void aeButton::mouseDown(wxMouseEvent& event)
{
    pressedDown = true;
    paintNow();
}
void aeButton::mouseReleased(wxMouseEvent& event)
{
    pressedDown = false;
    paintNow();
}
void aeButton::mouseEnteredWindow(wxMouseEvent& event)
{
    mouseOver = true;
    if (pressedDown)
    {
        pressedDown = false;
    }
    paintNow();
}
void aeButton::mouseLeftWindow(wxMouseEvent& event)
{
    mouseOver = false;
    if (pressedDown)
    {
        pressedDown = false;
    }
    paintNow();
}
```

Comment: wxBrush is not wxColor. Create a wxBrush object using that wxColor and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything that could explain why does the code above with `wxRED_BRUSH` and not RGB(10,10,10) brush, but two observations which could be helpful and are worth knowing about in any case:

1. Using `wxClientDC` is deprecated and doesn't work in many ports, including wxGTK3 and wxOSX, although it does still work in wxMSW in 3.0. You need to change your `paintNow()` to call `Refresh()`.
2. Using alpha is not supported with `wxBrush` and `wxDC` classes. To use semi-transparent brush, you need to use `wxGraphicsContext` for drawing.

I strongly recommend changing your code as indicated.

Comment: Can you mention the version of wxWidgets where wxClientDC has deprecated?

Comment: See the prominent "Note" in [its documentation](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.2/classwx_client_d_c.html)

Comment: The note doesn't say explicitly anything about deprecation.

Comment: It's not formally deprecated, you're not going to get warnings when using it, as this would affect too much code and there are still some cases where this class _can_ be used and there is no good replacement for it until [this](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/issues/12486) gets done. But you absolutely shouldn't use it for drawing any more.